# Why does all my sites inherit the HTTP header from the main site?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, http, headers

I have two sites on the same Nginx server.

The site www.example.com contains HTTP headers, but not the analytics.example.com

When I go to the analytics.example.com site there is an error message in the console :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://analytics.s1biose.com/' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket
>   endpoint 'ws://analytics.example.com:7890/'. This request has been
>   blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

I think this message is displayed because of the HTTP header:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
```

from www.example.com

But why analytics.example.com inherits HTTP header from www.example.com ?

The HTTP header should be applied to www.example.com but not to analytics.example.com because the 2 sites are totally different.

How to correct this problem ?

www.example.com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/www-example-com/web;
    index index.php;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    brotli on;
    brotli_comp_level 6;
    brotli_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    expires 1209600s;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        expires off;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

analytics.example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name analytics.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://analytics.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name analytics.example.com;
    root /var/www/analytics-example-com/web;
    index report.html;

    auth_basic "Protected";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/analytics-example-com/web/.htpasswd;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/analytics.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/analytics.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than guess the cause please get your response headers (Chrome developer tools can do it) and edit your post to include them. I expect that message is because  a secure page is trying to load an insecure resource, rather than a header that probably isn't there.

Comment: I'll still venture a guess that the error has nothing to do with your CSP headers and everything to do with the lack of upgrade-insecure-requests which effectively means insecure assets (or websockets) won't be loaded if the page is served over HTTPS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inheritance between `server { }` blocks.

Many browsers would block mixed content by default even when you don't have any content security policy headers sent.

It is to be expected in most cases that an `http://` or `ws://` resource (your exact case) would be blocked from loading on an `https://` website.

nginx has nothing to do with it. Simply update any reference to their secure equivalents (`wss://`, `https://`) in your app's HTML output.